# flutter) how can I convert String to Time?

Tags: flutter, datetime, timeofday

Hi i have an array contains

```
 List<dynamic> am = ['09:00', '09:30', '10:00', '10:30', '11:00', '11:30'];
```

and if they are selected

```
String time = '09:00'
```

how can I change time to the DateTime value or TimeOfDay

Answer (score 2):

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

if your time format is fixed (for example "hours:minutes" ) you can use this method

```
 DateTime? _convertStringToDateTime(String time){
    DateTime? _dateTime;
    try{
      _dateTime =  DateFormat("hh:mm").parse(time);
    }catch(e){
     }
    return _dateTime;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
TimeOfDay toTimeOfDay(String time){
  List<String> timeSplit = time.split(":");
  int hour = int.parse(timeSplit.first);
  int minute = int.parse(timeSplit.last);
  return TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

https://pub.dev/packages/date_format

See this package, By means of this package you can format your DateTime.